# cassandra where condition on 1 of 2 composite key giving error

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

My table structure is like this

```
CREATE TABLE tracks_by_album (
 album_title TEXT,
 album_year INT,
 performer TEXT STATIC,
 album_genre TEXT STATIC,
 track_number INT,
 track_title TEXT,
 PRIMARY KEY ((album_title, album_year), track_number)
);
```

When I am trying select query with where condition on 1 of 2 composite keys giving error

```
ReadFailure: Error from server: code=1300 [Replica(s) failed to execute read] 
message="Operation failed - received 0 responses and 1 failures" info=
{'failures': 1, 'received_responses': 0, 'required_responses': 1, 'consistency': 'ONE'}
```

But when I am trying with both composite keys(primary key) in my where condition  its working.

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is expected behavior all parts of the partitioning key have to be provided if partitioning key is composite. i.e. you have to specify album_title and album_year, eventually you can put album_year into and `IN` but that's pretty much it.